# TypeError: can't concat bytes to int

Tags: python

I am trying to hash the filename and then save into DB. I am using Flask and Python 3.4

This is the code for upload:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_pic():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        try:
            extension = file.filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower()
        except IndexError as e:
            abort(404)
        if file and check_extension(extension):
            # Salt and hash the file contents
            filename = md5(file.read() + str(round(time.time() * 1000))).hexdigest() + '.' + extension
            file.seek(0)  # Move cursor back to beginning so we can write to disk
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_DIR'], filename))
            add_pic(filename)
            gen_thumbnail(filename)
            return redirect(url_for('show_pic', filename=filename))
        else:  # Bad file extension
            abort(404)
    else:
        return render_template('upload.html')
```

When i post the form, i get this error traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Ajay\PycharmProjects\codehackr-upload\flaskgur.py", line 70, in upload_pic
    filename = md5(file.read() + (round(time.time() * 1000))).hexdigest() + '.' + extension
TypeError: can't concat bytes to int
```

I dont know whats wrong is happening, please enlighten me.

Thanks.

Comment: Your traceback doesn't match the code. The code is fixed already, but the traceback shows that you are running different code.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to concatenate the result of `file.read()` with the result of `round(time.time() * 1000))`, which is an integer. That's why you get the error:

```
TypeError: can't concat bytes to int
```

Try to cast the integer:

```
file.read() + bytes(round(time.time() * 1000)))
```

But as @Lev Levitsky noticed, it looks like your code already has the correction: are you sure to run the last version of your code?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to convert it to `bytes` type?

Comment: You're wright! Don't know why I made this mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as julienc wrote, the problem was trying to concatenate the result of `file.read()`, of type `bytes`, with the result of `round(time.time() * 1000))`, which was an `int`.

BUT DON'T DO WHAT'S SHOWN IN THE OTHER ANSWER! Keep calm and carry on reading...

## How to create bytes in Python 3

```py
# (1)
bytes(12)                == b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

# (2)
bytes([12])              == b'\x0c'
bytes([444])             -> ValueError("bytes must be in range(0, 256)")
bytes([0x01, 0xBC])      == b'\x01\xbc'

# (3)
( 12).to_bytes(8, 'big') == b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0c'
(444).to_bytes(8, 'big') == b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\xbc'

# (4)
str(12).encode('utf8')   == b'12'
```

#### (1) Create `bytes` of length `n` that is empty (full of zeroes)

This is rarely what you want. Beware!

In the context of this question `md5(file.read() + bytes(round(time.time() * 1000)))` hashes the file contents and then around 1.5 trillion empty bytes. Technically it still does what's needed, but ugh, for what a computing cost :-)

#### (2) Create `bytes` of length `n` containing the specified value(s)

Each source value must be just between 0 and 255 to fit into a byte.

Of course, could be also written with a tuple, but it's a bit uglier for the case of length 1: `bytes((12,))`

#### (3) Create `bytes` as a native/binary representation of an integer

This is the answer to the original question, how to convert an integer to a stream etc.

But now you need to think about some low-level things, like number of bytes of the output and the endianness (byte order). See [`int.to_bytes()` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) for details.

Of course, the extra parentheses are needed only with a literal value `12` in this example. They can be omitted when using a variable or other expression.

#### (4) Create bytes from the specified text (`str`).

An alternative to the above, sometimes you don't need or want to think about the low-level considerations and then the same goal can be accomplished by just hashing (or whatever) the simple human textual representation of the value.

Of course, `'ascii'` or something else could be used instead of `'utf8'` in this example. But why not to train the muscle memory with what you want almost universally anywhere else?